# Pynput ImportError - Failed to execute script

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pynput

I'm using the pine project and improving some things in object identification in the game, but when I try to convert to .exe using pyinstaller this message comes up.

[image]

Link of project pine : https://github.com/petercunha/Pine

Comment: hi @7VK! Did the below answer address your initial query that is in the question? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/791774) it to signal others that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to `pynput`'s recent changes. See [this](https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/issues/312) issue and please try:

```
pyinstaller --console --onefile --hidden-import "pynput.keyboard._win32" --hidden-import "pynput.mouse._win32" pine.py
```

which incorporates the needed backends that pyinstaller can't directly see into the command with hidden imports. `--console` and `--onefile` are optional; you can replace them with your previous commands.

Comment: this message appeared ''The application cannot find Python39.dll'', I downloaded the .dll and placed it in the same folder as the .exe and now the following message appears in cmd ''TypeError: type 'types.GenericAlias' is not an acceptable base type ''

Comment: @7VK Do you have many Python installed in your system? Can you try `python -m pyinstaller --console --onefile --hidden-import "pynput.keyboard._win32" --hidden-import "pynput.mouse._win32" pine.py` and see if it works or gives error?

Comment: I had 2 python installed on the system, delete the oldest one and now I'm using only the most recent one, I did what I said and it appeared ''C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python. exe: In the module named pyinstaller'' I already installed pyinstaller, when I put pip install pyinstaller it says it's already installed

Comment: Python 3.9 might be a too new version for PyInstaller to work smoothly. Is downgrading an option? If not, I'm afraid I cannot help further. @7VK

Comment: @7VK Also, it seems you have still more than 1 Python in the system. Can you try replacing `python` in above command with `py`?

Comment: Ok, install now the version 3.7

Comment: Now i use only 1 python! After using the command ''python -m pyinstaller --console --onefile --hidden-import "pynput.keyboard._win32" --hidden-import "pynput.mouse._win32" pine.py''
I'm getting the following message ''C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: No module named pyinstaller

Comment: @7VK `pip install pyinstaller` then?

Comment: now when I run the .exe it starts giving signals that it will run and then the message appears on the cmd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ''pine.py, line 14, in <module>
  File ''lib\pine.py'', line 74, in start
FileNotFoundError: [Errno2] No Such file or directory: 'models\\coco-dataset.labels'
  Filed to execute pine script

Comment: @7VK Does that directory really exist `:)`? That's something specific to your program i think, not a generic error.

Comment: yes, look of project : https://github.com/petercunha/Pine

Comment: @7VK Okay, along with `pine.exe` do you have a `models` directory and inside there `coco-dataset.labels` file? You need to run the exe with these files near it.